# #DIV/0! when using an AVERAGEIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am using the formula shown in the picture and what I want it to do is average the MinOscilation value categorised by date. That way for example I can get an average for everything on 30/04/2021, 04/05/2021 and like that) but when I try to do that I get an #DIV/0! error and I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should be using `AVERAGEIFS` with that syntax, not `AVERAGEIF`.

Comment: Look the floating helper help. First argument is range and second is criteria on the previous range. Third one is the range to be averaged. So it should be `AVERAGEIF(G22:36, G40,H22:H36)`

Comment: @Rory Thank you. If you submit this as an answer I can mark it as this solving my issue.

Comment: Also need dollar signs to anchor the ranges G22:G36 and H22:H36

Comment: @TomSharpe I realised that a few minutes later. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for the `AVERAGEIFS` function. So either use that, or switch the arguments to the correct order for `AVERAGEIF`:

```
=AVERAGEIF($G$22:$G$36,G40,$H$22:$H$36)
```

Comment: I think, looking at the image posted by OP, that `G22` should be `G40` so it makes the average of each date from range `G40:G48`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, I think you are correct. Will amend, thanks.